# Using sidekiq in rails, how can I send messages to a bunch of users, each of which has a unique time they want to receive it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

Hey I have a rails application and a bunch of users and I want to send them a message once per day at a preferred local time of the user's choice. (A message is a text, email, or chatbot notification.)

I believe I could add something to my User model that would allow for something to be performed every 24 hours at the preferred time but I'm not sure specifically how to implement that AND I also don't know how to remove these jobs from the queue if, for example, the user changes their preferred time or they want to disable messages all together.

Any thoughts on how I could do this?

Comment: I'd run a periodic job every minute (or whatever is the granularity of your notification time settings) and fetch the users from the db whose notification time of day (adjusted for tz offset) is this minute. There are some sidekiq scheduling plugins, look them up.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your application hosted?
You can have a cron task or a scheduler (Heroku) that runs every hour (or every 10 minutes). It would query in a users preferences table searching for users who want to receive the email at this moment (or in a range near this moment, such as the next 10 minutes).

```
time = Time.now
@users = User.include(:settings).where(“settings.receive_email_at between ? and ?”, time, time + 10.minutes)
```

You may need some changes to handle timezones and to avoid sending duplicate emails, but that’s just an idea.

Comment: haha so I did this exact thing and everything kind of crashed and burned on me. I running on Heroku and I use the clockwork gem and Sidekiq. I have a worker that runs every 15 minutes and sees if it's the hour that the user should be receiving their message. During this job, if a user should receive a message, I push onto a MessageQueue table. Then every minute, another job runs that gets all undelivered messages from MessageQueue and sends them out. The issue I ran into was that users were receiving multiple messages from us, even with all the safeguards put in place. Not sure whats going on.

Comment: Well. This is the way to go. Just need some fixes in your code to avoid sending duplicate messages. You should try sending messages to you (or doing other task) instead of sending to the real users, just to test.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. Build two models - One to store user and its time mapping (`UserTimeMapping`) and the second one to create a unique entry for each day when a message is sent to user (`UserMessage`).

Write a cron task which runs every 10 minutes and pulls all the records from `UserTimeMapping` which are to be executed for next 10 minutes and schedules a worker task for the exact time (say `MessageTriggerWorker`). The worker has to check in `UserMessage` table whether a record exists for the given user_id for today and if yes it has to return without performing any task. If that is not the case then it should send the message and create a record in the `UserMessage` table.

Comment: Hey so I actually do something very similar. I run a worker every 15 minutes and runs through the users table and sees if a user is suppose to receive a message this hour. If so, then they are added to a Message Queue table. Separately, I run a job every minute that runs through all the Message Queue rows that haven't been delivered and after delivery, updates the row so it doesn't run again. Here's my issue: multiple messages are being sent to a user and I think it's a sidekiq issue. Not sure if you have any thoughts on why sidekiq might be queuing up multiple messages for a given user.

Comment: Sidekiq won't be causing issues, I guess your query would be wrong and that would be queuing multiple message same time.